# checkbox_tag check from comparing to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In my `users` table, I have a column `SkillType` that has values "1", "2" and "3".

I want to check `checkbox_tag` in my view file when `SkillType == "1"` and I am trying the below given code:

```
def new
    @user_basic=User.find(params[:id])
    #@user_education=Education.where(:UserID => params[:id])
end
```

And below given is my view file contents:

```
<td width="25%" align="left" style="vertical-align: bottom; color: #212121;" class="style6">
   <%= check_box_tag :SkillType, "active", 1, true %>
   <%= f.label(:SkillType, " Students") %>
</td>
```

But it is not checking the checkbox_tag.

Comment: Did you check whether @user_basic is nil or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your checkbox in view label by this--

```
<%if @user_basic.SkillType == "1" %>
  <%= check_box_tag :@user_basic.SkillType, :checked => true %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: using above code, I get an error "undefined method `SkillType' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: can you print your value in controller label by this--
Rails.logger.info("#{@user_basic.SkillType}")

becuase i have Doubt that you didn't get your thi value  @user_basic.SkillType at controller query

Comment: In controller page i am doing this "def new
   @user_basic=User.find(params[:id])
   #@user_education=Education.where(:UserID = params[:id])
  end" and also see in my post

Comment: What is the output of this "{@user_basic.SkillType}"

Answer (score 0):

In View

```
<%= check_box_tag :skill_type, :checked => get_status( @user_basic.SkillType) %>
```

In application_helper.rb

```
def get_status(skill_type)
  skill_type.eql?("1") ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**In view:**

```
<% unless @user_basic.blank? %>
    <% if @user_basic.SkillType.to_i == 1 %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'Skilltype', @user_basic.id, 1, true %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that works !!

Comment: I am getting an error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: That means @user_basic is nil. No records fetched. To avoid the error, please find the updated answer.

Comment: As per RESTful architecture, usually 'new' method is used for creating a new record. Here, I hope you want top display the users, so please use the given code in 'index' method and the view file should be index.html.erb